# How to return value if it is in a certain range in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am struggling with how to return value if it is in a certain range in excel. For example, say I have columns A, B, C, and D. And I want to check if the value in column B is *between* the values present in A and C, then, return said value in column D. Example:
[See picture here, please.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWEZb.png)

Here, 5 (B1) is indeed between 1 (A1) and 10 (C1), and so, 5 was returned in cell D5.

How can I do this using a function? My unsuccessful attempt was, at cell D5, I wrote:

```
=if(A1 < B1 < C1, B1)
```

But I keep getting an empty cell. Why is this? There are multiple resources on how to return (TRUE or FALSE) or (YES or NO), but I do not want either of those. I was the value itself to be returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`A1 < B1 < C1` is not logic that Excel recognizes.  It needs to be done with `AND`:

```
AND(A1 < B1, B1 < C1)
```

So:

```
=IF(AND(A1 < B1, B1 < C1),B1,"")
```

Comment: Now I see what I was going wrong. Thank you very much, good sir. I really appreciate it!

Comment: You might wish to extend this "noob"-level answer to include basic info about logic expressions - a single sentence or maybe two might become a jumpstart.  Noob-level answers are scarce on the net.